# ion spinner Does not rotate

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I use Ionic-angular and I use the following code in some parts of my application:

```
<ion-spinner name = "circles"> </ion-spinner>
```

I commanded

```
ionic capacitor run android
```

I ran my app on both my **real phone** and the **Android emulator**
And I have some problems

**The first problem:**

**My ion-spinners do not spin**

**The second problem:**

**I used two tabs at the bottom of the program that activate their style does not work**

[image: The first and second problem]

The third problem:
Some of the ionic icons are also invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I created a new project and used its styles. Many problems were fixed. But there are still some problems.
Did you use this method?
You can also use different spinners:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/spinner

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Yes, I used this method and even tested different spinners. But my problem was not solved!

Comment: Ionic has many problems. I hope you find the solution.